# Возникли проблемы с Git

Tags: git

Я начинающий в программировании, и было задано ознакомиться с Git-ом. Но при вводе команды
Git status, выбивает, как я понимаю, что находятся файлы в неотслеживаемых.Причём файлы с диска C, которые вообще никаким образом не связаны с какими либо прогами. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться в чём проблема
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Проблема скорей всего, что `git -status` выполнена не в директории проекта, а в какой-то другой (похоже на `%USERPROFILE%`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно ранее вы запустили команду `git init` в папке профиля пользователя (например, в C:\Users\user), и теперь для git весь ваш профиль пользователя выглядит как рабочий каталог проекта. Убедитесь, что там нет папки .git (вероятно есть, потому что команда `git status` в ином случае должна была сообщить об ошибке — проверил под Linux, но под Windows наверняка поведение то же).

Если в папке профиля пользователя есть папка .git, то просто удалите её (или, если опасаетесь удалять, переименуйте). После этого вам видимо потребуется запустить `git init` в той папке, где находится ваш проект (если вы это не сделали ранее).

Comment: спасибо большое, помогло